# Checking for a pattern of a number in C

Tags: c, pattern-matching, bit

I'm still new in C and I have to create a method that returns `0` or `1` if a number contains the binary pattern of the number decided as the pattern. For example, `check_pattern(10, 5)` returns `1` since `1010` contains the pattern `101`.

The issue I'm having is when the pattern only contains one bit at 1, situations like `100` or `1000`, where it disregards the least significant bits, and assumes the pattern's value is `1` instead of `4` or `8`.

Here is the code I've created:

```
int check_pattern(int value, int pattern) {
    while ((pattern & 1) == 0)
        pattern >>= 1;
    int pattern_x = pattern, mask = 0;
    while (pattern > 0) {
        mask |= pattern;
        pattern >>= 1;
    }
    while (value >= pattern_x) {
        if ((value & mask) == pattern_x)
            return 1;
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works when the least significant bit isn't `0` or when there are multiple bits of value `1`.

```
int main() {
    size_t arr_size = 4;
    int values[4] = {10, 11, 12, 13}, patterns[4] = {5, 9, 6, 7};
    char *ans;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        printf("%d: %d contains pattern %d? %s\n", i+1, values[i], patterns[i], 
                     ans = check_pattern(values[i], patterns[i])==1? "True":"False");
    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces these results, which are correct:

```
1: 10 contains pattern 5? True
2: 11 contains pattern 9? False
3: 12 contains pattern 6? True
4: 13 contains pattern 7? False
```

But changing the patterns to these values `patterns[4] = {4, 8, 4, 2}`, the results are all wrong:

```
1: 10 contains pattern 4? True
2: 11 contains pattern 8? True
3: 12 contains pattern 4? True
4: 13 contains pattern 2? True
```

They should all be false, but since only the most significant bit is of value `1` they end up all true. I think the comparison in my code is only being made with the value `1` and not `100`, not sure why.

I know I did something wrong, most likely related to my thought process, but I can't identify what it is.

Thank you very much for the help, I'll also listen to advice on how to improve the code overall!

Comment: Not related but ans should be char not char*

Comment: The first thing you do is removing 0 at the end of the pattern. That is why 0 at end are not taken into account.

Comment: Your working examples have all odd (non-even) patterns that have a 1 in bit 0, so they are not shifted right. Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to explain a little what you are doing in your code? Why for instance are you removing the zeros at the LSBs of your pattern? Explaining to others the decisions you took helps you find bugs and/or wrong choices.

Answer (score 1):

How I understand your question:

You want to take a pattern of `1`'s and `0`'s **which starts with a `1`**, store it in `int pattern` and look after this pattern in `int value`

That is possible  with this code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

bool check_pattern( int value, int pattern )
{
  if( pattern == 0 )
  {
    printf( "int pattern is 0: pattern not defined\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int mask = 0;
  int pattern_x = pattern;
  while( pattern_x != 0 )
  {
    mask |= pattern_x;

    pattern_x >>=1;
  }

  while( value != 0 )
  {
    if( (value & mask ) == pattern )
    {
      return true;
    }
    value >>= 1;
  }

  return false;
}
```

note that negative values of `int value` and `int pattern` are in the two's complement representation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly and if I'm not mistaken , maybe this will work for you :

```
int check_pattern(int val , int pattern){
    int counter = pattern ; 
    int mask = 0 ; 
    mask = ~mask ; 
    while(counter){
        counter >>= 1 ; 
        mask <<= 1 ; 
    }
    mask = ~mask ; 
    do
         if((val & mask) == pattern)
         return 1 ; 
    while (val >>= 1) ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

This creates a variable initialized to 0xFFFFFFFF.

```
int mask = 0 ; 
mask = ~mask ;
```

This will count how many bits you have in the `pattern` variable before the MSB , in a mask ... your mask is gonna be in the form 0xFFF....000  :

```
while(counter){
    counter >>= 1 ; 
    mask <<= 1 ; 
}
```

Invert the mask so we have it in the form 0x000...FFF

```
mask = ~mask ;
```

Now , we shift our value to the right , `&` it with `mask` and checking if it's equal to the pattern.